# send PHP string to C++

Tags: php, c++

I am trying to pass over from php a string into C++, i managed to figure out how to pass numbers, but it doesn't work for letters. Here's what i have that works for PHP

```
<?php 



$r = 5; 
$s =  12;
$x= 3;  
$y= 4; 
$q= "Hello World"; 
$c_output=`project1.exe $r $s $x $y $q`; // pass in the value to the c++ prog 
echo "<pre>$c_output</pre>"; //received the sum 
 //modify the value in php and output 
echo "output from C++ programm is" . ($c_output + 1);

?>
```

This sends the variables r,s,x,y, and q to the C++ programm project1.exe and IT WORKS, but the problem is that it doesn't work for the string variable $q.

Here's the code that I have in my C++ programm, it's simple:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdlib> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(int in, char* argv[]) { 
 int val[2]; 
 for(int i = 1; i < in; i++) { // retrieve the value from php 
  val[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]); 
 }  
 double r = val[0];
double s = val[1];
double x = val[2];
double y = val[3];

double q = val[4]; // here's the problem, as soon as i try to define val[4] as a string or char, it screws up
 cout << r;
 cout <<s;
cout << x;
cout << y;
cout << q;

  // will output to php 
 return 0; 

 }
```

It works, but for the string "Hello world" which i pass through $q from PHP doesn't give me the string back (i know it's defined as a double, but as soon as i try to change it to a string or a char variable the code just doesn't compile).

Please explain to me how i have to go around this problem so that $q can be processed as a string. FYI, I am a newbie to programming (6 months in).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for letters because you are doing `atoi(..)`(which converts char-string to integer) in the C++ program.

Have some means of letting the program know what to expect -- whether a number or a string. May be the first argument can help the program differentiate, like may be the following:

```
$c_output = `project1.exe nnsnns 1 2 string1 3 4 string2`
```

Then you could do:

```
for(int i = 0/*NOTE*/,len=strlen(argv[1]); i < len; i++) { // retrieve the value from php 
    if (argv[1][i] == 'n'){
         //argv[2+i] must be an integer
    }else if (argv[1][i] == 's'){
        //argv[2+i] is a string
    }
}
```

Of course you should check if `(strlen(argv[1]) == in-2)`.

BTW, in the C++ code above, `val` is a array holding 2 ints; and you are trying to access much beyond index 1.

---

To pass one single string to the C++ you would do something like the following:

```
$output = `project1.exe $q`; //Read below.
```

**NOTE**: `$q` must be a single word. No spaces, no extra characters like '|', '&', or any other character which the shell might interpret differently. `$q` must be clean before you pass that on to C++ Program. If $q is more than one word, use quotes.

C++ Part (Just try the following, then you can modify as you go along)

```
cout<<argv[1]<<endl;
```

Comment: I think i am overcomplicating it, what if i just had a php variable which was a string and just wanted to pass on that string to C++? Like in an HTML form i type in "John", i make that HTML form = $q in PHP, then i pass $q into C++ but i want the $q to just be a string, how would i declare that? I tried adding your code but it seems to give me infinities.

Answer (score 0):

Try not converting the final argument using atoi(argv[i]). Just keep it as argv[i].

```
for(int i = 1; i < in-1; i++)
{
    val[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]); 
}
q = argv[i];
```

Comment: I get an error if i put q=argv[i] like that. Maybe i am just complicating the entire thing, i don't think i need the for loop at all. What i have is 5 HTML forms into the first 4 i put in numbers, into the fifth one i put in letters like "John". I'm trying for the fifth input, which i declared as HTML variable q to php q = $q to go to C++ as a string so that when i go like cout<<q; it gives me the letters "John"? If you just had to pass on letters into C++, how would you make it so that it's a string in C++?